# slider for choropleth map plotly shows error - <ipython-input-17-c5022c9e0aab>:13: SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: python, plotly, slider, google-colaboratory, choropleth

I am trying to add a slider for my choropleth map using plotly. I have been unable to see the map in google colab but jupyter notebook has worked fine.

I have a dataset with values for each country of the world over a period of years. I want to make a slider underneath so you can scroll through the years and see the colours change. I have been able to get data from one year, but I cannot get the slider to appear under my map, and I get a large pink error message saying the value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Please find attached my code

```
pip install chart-studio
import pandas as pd
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as po
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, pilot

df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesjeffery77/jamesjeffery77.github.io/main/share-electricity-low-carbon_fullDataset.csv")
year=1985

### create empty list for data object:    
data_slider = []

# Populate data object
for year in df.year.unique():
    #select year
    df2=df[(df['year']==year)]
    
    for col in df2.columns:
        df2[col] = df2[col].astype(str)
        
    #dictionary with date for current year
    data_one_year = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        locations=df2['code'],
        z=df2['percentage'].astype(float),
        text=df2['country'],)
    #add data to next year
    data_slider.append(data_one_year)

#steps for the slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(data_slider)):
    step=dict(method='restyle',
              args=['visible',[False] * len(data_slider)],
              label='year {}'.format(i+1985))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

##  create the sliders object from the steps 
sliders = [dict(active=0, pad={"t": 1}, steps=steps)]  

#layout such that there is a global view
layout = dict(title = 'Global GDP - natural earth',
              geo = dict( projection = {'type':'natural earth'},
                         showlakes = True, 
                         lakecolor = 'rgb(0,191,255)'))

fig = dict(data=data_slider, layout=layout) 

#plot graph
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the `value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` warning, you can set the columns as strings in one step - you don't need to loop through each column name separately.

```
# Populate data object
for year in df.year.unique():
    #select year
    df2=df[(df['year']==year)]
    
    df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(str)
        
    #dictionary with date for current year
    data_one_year = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        locations=df2['code'],
        z=df2['percentage'].astype(float),
        text=df2['country'],)
    #add data to next year
    data_slider.append(data_one_year)
```

After this change, I ran your code in `Google Colab`, and I am able to display the map.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Derek! Yes I have managed to get to that stage as well, however the slider still doesn't seem to appear at the bottom. It looks like it is just taking data from one year in my dataset, however I have several years I would like to have included so I can represent the changes using a slider. I just can't work out why my slider code isn't working! :( Thanks!

Comment: @jamesj477 if you still haven't figured this out, i'd be glad to take another look and see what's preventing the slider from working